# How to resolve Selenium Webdriver "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with.." issue?

Tags: html, css, selenium-webdriver

I am doing a click on the 'edit' element in below image.

[image]

the html of 'edit' and its parent is:

```html
<ul id="opsbar-edit-issue_container" class="toolbar-group pluggable-ops">
  <li class="toolbar-item"><a id="edit-issue" title="Edit this issue" class="toolbar-trigger issueaction-edit-issue" href="/secure/EditIssue!default.jspa?id=482933"><span class="icon aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-edit"></span> <span class="trigger-label">Edit</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

For such a seemingly easy task to click on 'edit', I got the "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with.." error if I am doing:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("edit-issue")).click();
```

**What is the proper way to click the 'edit'?**

I have tried to wait for 'edit' to be visible by:

```
(new WebDriverWait(myDriver, 10)).until(
                ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("edit-issue")));
```

it times out.

I also tried:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) myDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", myDriver.findElement(By.id("edit-issue")));
```

it doesn't work.

I have checked DOM tab of Firebug for "edit-issue" element. I did not find any visibility attribute that set to 'false', or where should I look?

Comment: Is the element in an iframe? It looks like it might be...

Comment: @lambo477 it's not. the container 'opsbar-edit-issue_container' can be selected and clicked with no problem.

Comment: Have you checked that the element is actually visible immediately prior to clicking it? Run `driver.saveScreenshot` to save an image of the browser immediately prior to the click. If the element isn't visible (ie it is out of shot due to browser scroll), then I have a potential solution for you

Comment: @lambo477 I can see the element when test is performing. The thing is that for parent/container of 'edit-issue', everything is fine.  Wait for ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated of parent, or click on parent never fail. But same operation fail on 'edit-issue' every time.

Comment: Can you give me a URL?

Comment: @lambo477 https://jira.atlassian.com/  you can use this username/passwd combination to login(peter.skiva@gmail.com/peter.skiva@gmail.com) or create an account by yourself. Then first create an issue, next search for issues will lead to this page, or if you're using my account, simply search "reported by me"